# How to package ClickOnce installer as MSI?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, clickonce

I have an excel plugin that I want to distribute as a single installation package, preferably MSI. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've created many office addin installers for customers and basically have it down to a template starting point.  For pointers see my blog article:

[VSTO 4 ( 2010 ) Lessons Learned](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/10/vsto-4-2010-lessons-learned.html)

ClickOnce is still technically used but the |vstolocal tag is used to run from source and not deploy to the click once cache.   Basically you get a per-machine MSI experience and a setup.exe that makes sure all of your prereqs are present.

Comment: Your question didn't ask that.  There are ways of implementing autoupdating MSI's.  Ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create an MSI installer from scratch, not try to wrap your ClickOnce package. Any MSI package, no matter [the tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_installer#Tools) you use to build it, can install the addin, as long as it install the files and registry entries required, as documented in the following [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx).

If you are looking for a free tool and have some time on your hands to learn using it than [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is the best.